# How to distribute a list into sub-lists, keeping the original order of the elements?

Tags: java, list, split, java-8

How to split a list into a given number of lists, taking the elements in order and distributing them to the sub-lists (so not partitioning the list)?

I would like to do this as "nice" as possible (using Java 8 features or Guava or something similar.

- Example list: `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]`
- Should be split in 3 : `[1 4 7]` `[2 5]` `[3 6]`
- Should be split in 2 : `[1 3 5 7]` `[2 4 6]`

Comment: How are the elements distributed to their respective partition?

Comment: @Flown 1st element to 1st sub-list, 2nd element to 2nd sub-list, 3rd element to 1st sub-list, etc (in the example of 2 sub-lists) ; just take them in order from the original list and distribute them in that order to the sub-lists

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the source list supports efficient random access, like `ArrayList` does, you can use

```
IntStream.range(0, source.size()).boxed()
  .collect(groupingBy(i->i%listCount, LinkedHashMap::new, mapping(source::get, toList())));
```

e.g.

```
List<Integer> source=IntStream.range(0, 20).boxed().collect(toList());
System.out.println(source);
int listCount=5;

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> collect = IntStream.range(0, source.size()).boxed()
  .collect(groupingBy(i->i%listCount, LinkedHashMap::new, mapping(source::get, toList())));
// in case it really has to be a List:
List<List<Integer>> result=new ArrayList<>(collect.values());

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 5, 10, 15]
[1, 6, 11, 16]
[2, 7, 12, 17]
[3, 8, 13, 18]
[4, 9, 14, 19]
```

Comment: I like this, I was struggling to think about how to keep a count inside the stream

Comment: You can even avoid boxing every integer from 0 to n by using the standard collect on `IntStream`, although it seems a bit overkill tho: `.collect(LinkedHashMap::new, (m, i) -> m.computeIfAbsent(i % size, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(list.get(i)), (m1, m2) -> m2.forEach((k,v) -> m1.merge(k, v, (l1,l2) -> { l1.addAll(l2); return l1; })) );`

Comment: @Alexis C: that’s what I wanted to avoid here. Especially the merge function. It’s a pity that `Map.mergeAll` has been forgotten…

Comment: @Ash French: there is no general clean way to get an element position in a stream. Using `IntStream.range` and mapping to the element is the canonical way for random access sources, but for other kinds of streams, you’re out of luck.

Comment: @Belun: collectors are designed to be combinable and while the nesting might not look as elegant as the chaining of operations, they are more powerful as they are *extensible* and all other terminal stream operations can be considered just special cases of them. In fact, with the Java 9 additions of `flatMapping` and `filtering`, almost every stream operation is covered by a matching collector, then combinable with other collectors, most notably `groupingBy`/`partitioningBy`…

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could put all your lists into a map, then you just need to get the sub-lists out of the map

```
int count = 0;
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> mapLists = list.stream()
                            .peek(i -> count ++)
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> count % numOfSubLists))
```

Another way using Guava

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition(java.util.List,%20int)

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = Lists.partition(list, noOfPartitions);
```

Comment: Guava Lists.partition - Returns consecutive sublists of a list. Not I want. I need them distributed the other way. The groupBy solution might work

Comment: regarding the peek solution : peek is for debugging not messing with data (maybe use map() instead, but that does not work with external mutable variable)

Comment: you might be able to get rid of peek, and just modify the count in the groupingBy by doing something like this `groupingBy(i -> ++count % numberOfSubLists)`